# Change of content notification

Tags: php, flash

Php updates the xml files in certain period of  time. Is there any possible way to send a change of content notification from php to flash application. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the PHP runs on your server and the flash is in your web browser, then no. Best you can do is let the PHP side allow the flash side to ask if the content changed and then poll from the flash side.

Comment: polling or an always open XMLSocket connect to your server will be your best bet. What you want is called "push notifications".